# Multithreading fitness calculation of a sequence in a math function

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, multithreading, c++14

I wrote this program to calculate a value from an energy function from a sequence of 1s and -1s. The problem here is to find the lowest possible fitness for a function (note that this is original function; in my implementation I pre calculate power of c `c*c` and  put it in the thread so I avoid calling a method):

```
double EnergyFunction::evaluate(vector<short> field) {
  double e = 0.0;
  int l = field.size()
  for (int k = 1; k < l; k++){
    double c = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0, j = k; j < l; i++, j++) {
        c += field[i] * field[j];
    }
    e += c*c;
  }
  return l*l / ( e+e );
}
```

It uses multithreading and one thread `printOut()` for outputing data to standard output stream. In thread `printOut()` there is a `mutex` for outputting without a data race. With this I hoped to achieve no locking of other threads, where computation is done.

Concerns:

1. Is this the right way to do it without locking other threads?

   The sequence is randomly mutated every loop iteration, so every iteration I am copying the sequence from the best sequence. That way I start every time with the current best sequence and mutate it to get a new fitness.
2. Is copying the whole sequence every iteration necessary to get best solution every time, or is there any other way to get the same effect? I cannot think of it. Also bear in mind the algorithm isn't so important than performance. The point is still to achieve the lowest possible fitness but I want to make it as simple as possible and as fast as possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <atomic>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <array>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>

static const bool lookupTable[2] = {false, true};
static const short lookupTableNum[2] = {-1, 1};
unsigned int lookupTableCPower[305] = {};
static const unsigned long iterations = 100000000;
static const short l = 305;
static const short lh = 153;

std::atomic<unsigned long> overallGeneration (1);
std::atomic<unsigned short> bestFitness (std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max());
std::array<std::atomic<bool>, lh> bestSequence;

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());

std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned short> distDim(0.0, lh);
std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned short> dist(0.0, 1.0);

std::mutex mtx;

void threadOptimize();
void printOut(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 305; i++)
        lookupTableCPower[i] = i * i;
    
    int numberOfThreads = (int)std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::thread *threads = new std::thread[numberOfThreads];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
        threads[i] = std::thread(threadOptimize);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
        threads[i].join();
    
    std::cout << "Program ended." << std::endl;
    
    delete [] threads;
    return 0;
}

void threadOptimize() {
    bool seq[l];
    for(short i = 0; i < lh; i++)
        seq[i] = lookupTable[dist(mt)];
    
    std::copy(seq, seq + lh, bestSequence.begin());
    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    while(overallGeneration.load(std::memory_order_acquire) < iterations) {
        for(int i = 0; i  < distDim(mt);++i)
            seq[distDim(mt)] ^= true;
        
        bool even = false;
        for(int i = 152, j = 154; i >= 0 && j < 305; i--,j++) {
            if(even)
                seq[j] = seq[i] ^ true;
            else
                seq[j] = seq[i];
            even ^= true;
        }
        
        unsigned int newFitness = 0;
        for (int k = 1; k < l; ++k) {
            short c = 0;
            for(int i = 0, j = k; j < l; ++i,++j) {
                c += lookupTableNum[(seq[i] ^ seq[j])];
            }
            newFitness += lookupTableCPower[(c >= 0) ? c : -c];
        }
        
        ++overallGeneration;
        if (newFitness < bestFitness.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            bestFitness.store(newFitness,std::memory_order_release);
            std::copy(seq, seq+lh, bestSequence.begin());
            
            std::thread t1(printOut, begin);
            t1.detach();
        } else
            std::copy(bestSequence.begin(), bestSequence.end(), seq);
    }
}

void printOut(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin) {
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-begin).count();
    
    duration /= 1000;
    duration++;
    
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    std::cout << (overallGeneration.load(std::memory_order_acquire) / (duration)) << " " << bestFitness.load(std::memory_order_acquire) << " ";
    for(short i = 0; i < l; i++)
        std::cout << bestSequence[i].load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I am also trying to remove branch prediction and pre-calculate numbers for the energy function.

Comment: Feel free to post a follow-up with the revised code. Or, preferably, wait some more for other answers and thén post a follow-up with the edited code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `std::mt19937` is not thread safe but you use the global `mt` from each thread without synchronization. Instead declare an initialize it in `threadOptimize` to give each thread its own RNG.

Same with `bestSequence` surround each copy to and from it with a mutex guard like you do when printing out.

The following for loop doesn't quite do what you think it does.

```
for(int i = 0; i  < distDim(mt);++i)
    seq[distDim(mt)] ^= true;
```

the `distDim` in the condition is reevaluated each time so it will likely never reach the max amount of iterations. You can solve that by going in reverse order:

```
for(int i = distDim(mt); i  > 0;--i)
    seq[distDim(mt)] ^= true;
```

But even then it won't be a perfect manipulation.

Comment: I edited my program with your suggestions. For that loop part I don't really care if it doesn't do what i think it does. .) i just wanted random behaviour.